# MVC bind jQuery datepicker to properity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

first of all, please excuse my English.
I am doing web application in MVC, and have a problem with binding jQuery datepicker to Model properities. If i bind the datepicker to Model properities (like a "test" in code below), everything works, but I have a Model that contains my own class, and that class contains a property which i need bind datepicker to and i dont know how...

ViewModel

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    //ViewModel 
    public Filtr Fil { get; set; }
    public DateTime test { get; set; }

}
```

Class in ViewModel

```
public class Filtr
{
    [Display(Name = "Date from:")]
    public DateTime? DatumFrom { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date to:")]
    public DateTime? DatumTo { get; set; }
}
```

Part of Index.cshtml

```
@model aAKV.Models.MainViewModel 
.
.
.     
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#Fil.DateFrom').datetimepicker({
            lang: 'cs',
            formatDate: 'd.m.Y',
            formatTime: 'H:i',
            format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
            dayOfWeekStart: 1,
            step: 15,
            timepicker: true,
            mask: true
        });            

    });
</script>
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">

        @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Fil.DateFrom)
             @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fil.DateFrom, new { @class = "date-picker" })
.
.
.
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Look at the html your code is generating - its `jQuery('#Fil_DateFrom')` - `_` (underscore) not `.` (dot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your code isn't working is because `@Html.TextBoxFor()` creates an input with `Fil_DateFrom` as the id. Not `Fil.DateFrom`.

You can try any of the options based on your requirement:

1) You can change it to: `$('#Fil_DateFrom').datetimepicker({`

2) But the above `id` might confuse some one else looking at your code and make them wonder where `Fil_DateFrom` is coming from. So you can assign a unique `id` to the input like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fil.DateFrom, new { id="date-from", @class ="date-picker"})
```

And then in your script `$('#date-from').datetimepicker({`

3) Another option, would be to target based on the `class`:

`$('.date-picker').datetimepicker({`: This will add the `datepicker` to **all** the inputs on the page with `date-picker` class. This approach won't work if you want different `settings` to different `datepickers`.

Let's say you want to disable weekends on your `DateFrom` datepicker, but allow weekends on `DateTo` datepicker. Then you'd have to assign unique `id`s to both inputs and follow the approach 2.

Answer (score 0):

The ID will be rendered differently (as explained by adiga). Also if you plan to have multiple datepickers on the screen it is better to use css class instead of ID so it is applied to all at once.

Please use css class selector instead

`jQuery('.date-picker').datetimepicker({`